# Downloading files using media view in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to download 4 different files through 4 different links. I am using the Media view to download the files, but I have to hardcode the file name in the download functions in the controller:

```
function download () { 
    $this->view = 'Media'; 
    $params = array( 
          'id' => 'example.zip', 
          'name' => 'example', 
          'download' => true, 
          'extension' => 'zip', 
          'path' => APP . 'files' . DS 
   ); 
   $this->set($params); 
}
```

This works fine for one file.  Now, for links number 2,3,4, do I need to create 3 different actions and give different file names in them, or is there a way in which I can use download() to only download the respective file depending on which link has been clicked?

Answer (score 7):

That's what variables are for. Generic example:

```
function download($fileId) {
    $file = // find the file you want to serve based on $fileId
    $pathInfo = pathinfo($file['path']);

    $this->view = 'Media'; 
    $params = array( 
          'id'        => $file['name'],
          'name'      => $pathInfo['filename'], 
          'extension' => $pathInfo['extension'], 
          'download'  => true, 
          'path'      => APP . 'files' . DS 
   ); 
   $this->set($params); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In CakePhp 2.x you will get error `The view for YourController::download() was not found.`

Use **viewClass** field in CakePHP 2.x:

```
$this->viewClass = 'Media';
```

See [Media Views — CakePHP Cookbook v2.x documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html)

*UPD*: Media Views are deprecated since CakePHP 2.3, and [`CakeResponse::file()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file) should be used:

```
$this->response->file($file['path'], array('download' => true, 'name' => 'foo'));
return $this->response;
```

Comment: It should be noted, though, that in 2.x the MediaView is deprecated anyway. So it is better to leverage the new Response class here instead.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I updated the answer according this. Thank you