# Upload and retrieve image in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, upload, store

I have following code to upload a file in cakephp

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Users';

    function index() {
        $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all'));
    }

    function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your user data has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->uploads() && $this->User->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(_('Upload saved', true));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(_('Upload not saved.Please try again', true));
            }
        }
    }

    function uploads() {
        $uploads_dir = '/uploads';
        $users = $this->request->data['Upload']['file'];
        if ($users['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($users['User']['file'], $uploads_dir)) {
                $this->User->saveAll($this->data);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function edit($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = $this->User->read();
        } else {
            if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your user details has been updated.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }

     function delete($id) {
      $this->User->delete($id);
      $this->Session->setFlash('This user has been deleted.');
      $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
      } 
}
```

When I'm trying to upload, the file is uplaoding but I need the file uploaded to be viewed when the hyperlink given for each .jpeg to be displayed but I'm getting the error as

" The requested address '/Users/app/webroot/index.php/uploads' was not found on this server."

Also please help me how to store the uploaded image in another folder

PS:: code should b purely in CakePHP

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the folder used for uploading files have sufficient permissions and you can use Cakephp Media view to download files. For your reference,check this.
[Downloading files using media view in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905555/downloading-files-using-media-view-cakephp)

Use image name or image id as an argument in function download and change path to 
'path'      => APP . 'uploads' . DS

"uploads" folder should be inside webroot directory.